# Assign HTML attribute with PHP

Tags: php, html

Hello I'm trying to send one variable with POST (Hello Angel). That is the code:

```
<form action="dos.php" method="post" name="compra">
  <input name="id_txt" type="hidden" value=<?php echo "Hello Angel" ?>/>
  <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send" />
</form>
```

when in the other page show the variable, only shows up space (only Hello). That is the code:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['id_txt']))
    echo $_POST['id_txt'] 
?>
```

So, how Can I show all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote your value like this:

```
<input name="id_txt" type="hidden" value="<?php echo "Hello Angel"; ?>" />
```

When you don't put quotes around an HTML attribute value it only takes the first word as the value.

Comment: There is also a PHP function called [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) that will make sure that whatever you are echoing will work inside a HTML attribute even double quotes, just update your `<?php ?>` block to this: `value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("Hello \"Hacker\"<script>alert('Hi')</script>"); ?>"`

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the quotes around the input value

Change:

```
<input name="id_txt" type="hidden" value=<?php echo "Hello Angel" ?> />
```

To:

```
<input name="id_txt" type="hidden" value="<?php echo "Hello Angel" ?>" />
```